# UIWebView override url

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift

I want to create an iPhone WebView App. But there is a problem, if I click on some buttons, it opens the normal and not the mobile version.

I did create the same WebView app on Android and there I solve the problem with this code

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
        {
            if(!url.toLowerCase().contains("http://www.example.com/"))
            {
                webView.loadUrl(url + "?mt=1");
                return true;
            }
        return false;
            }
        });
```

How can I do this on xcode?

Thank you very much

Best wishes

Dominik

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same using the UIWebViewDelegate protocol.

I think you can achieve the required result by changing the NSURLRequest within the delegate function 
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request.......

```
//delegate methods
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{


    //use NSURLRequest object request , to manage the request.
 //use NSURLRequest object request , to manage the request.
    NSURL *urL=request.URL;
    NSString *urlStr=[urL absoluteString];
    NSLog(@"URLL %@",urlStr);
    if([urlStr isEqualToString:@"http://www.google.com/"]){
        urL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com"];
        request=[request initWithURL:urL];
        [webView loadRequest:request];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    //start of request
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //finished loading
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

}




 - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        //error
    }
```

This will work for sure. I am using above code to load www.yahoo.com when www.google.com is requested.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, but it does not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Thank you. I used your code, but there are 2 error messages. At [request initWithURL:urL]; (expression result unused) and [self updateAddress:request]; (no visible @interface for "ViewControler" declares the update selector "updateAdress:".

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: I just made some edits. actually the code was copied from my code base.Even though I published all the delegate functions , you just need the function shouldStartLoadWithRequest: only. So I didn't checked the others.Sorry for that.

Comment: I am using a function named updateAdress: in my view controller and if you add a same function in your view controller you can get rid of the  error. or just delete the line that calls the function as you don't need it.